# why does the variable become 0 suddenly?(c language)

Tags: c, for-loop, char, cs50, c-strings

i was practicing basic so i write a code to ask about user name and then i wanted to print user name character by character , then the whole name and the length of it and at the end the even numbers  characters of the user name like the 2nd,4th and so on
i got two problems first the variable holding name length become zero at the last for cycle
my second problem was the even characters as i get odd ones too

i entered the user name : james
i expected the out put to be :

```
j
5
a 
5
m
5
e
5
s
5
hello james , your name has 5 characters
ae
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("whats your name ? ");
    int x = strlen(name);
    char new[4] = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n" ,name[i] );
        if ( (i+1) % 2  == 0)
        {
            strcat(new,&name[i]);
        }
            printf("%i\n",x);
    }

    printf("hello %s ,your name has %i characters \n", name,x);
    printf("%s\n",new);
}
```

```
whats your name ? james
j
5
a
0
hello james ,your name is 0 characters long
ames
```

Comment: Step 1.  Stop using `string`.  It is an unnecessary obfuscation that is causing confusion rather than clarifying anything.

Comment: What do you expect `strcat(new,&name[i]);` to do?  It feels like you are trying to append a single character to `new`, but that is not what that line actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entered a string `"james"` that contains 6 characters including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

```
whats your name ? james
```

And you declared a character array that has only `4` elements.

```
char new[4] = "";
```

In this if statement

```
    if ( (i+1) % 2  == 0)
    {
        strcat(new,&name[i]);
    }
```

when for example `i` is equal to `1` the string pointed to by the pointer expression `name + 1` is appended to the character array `new`.

```
        strcat(new,&name[i]);
```

This is the following string (represented as a character array) `{ 'a', 'm', 'e', 's', '\0' }`. As it is seen the string contains `5` characters including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.  As a result this call of `strcat` results in overwritting memory outside the array `new` that invokes undefined behavior.

There is no need to use the function `strcat` because instead of storing only one character in the array `new` the function tries to append a whole substring.

You could write for example

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n" ,name[i] );
    if ( (i+1) % 2  == 0)
    {
        new[i / 2] = name[i];
    }
        printf("%i\n",x);
}
```

Pay attention to that the array `new` will contain a string because all its elements were initially initialized by zeroes in the array declaration

```
char new[4] = "";
```

On the other hand, using the magic number `4` in the array declaration is unsafe. Instead you could declare for example a variable length array like

```
int x = strlen(name);
char new[x / 2 + 1];
memset( new, 0, x / 2 + 1 );
```

In this case your program will work even if the user will enter a more long name.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the `new` buffer is not large enough to hold the data you are writing to it.  I suspect the primary confusion is the incorrect usage of `strcat`.  When you write `strcat(new,&name[i]);`, it does *not* copy a single character to the end of `new`.  If `name` is "james" and `i` is 2, then `&name[i]` is the address of the 'm' and `strcat` attempts to copy the string "mes" to the end of `new`.  If you just want to copy a single character, `strcat` is the wrong tool.  IMO, this confusion is exacerbated by the use of the `string` typedef, whose only purpose is to confuse students.  Stop using `string` and use `char *` instead.  You *must* understand this detail if you are ever to understand C.

If you want to iterate through the string and copy every other character into an array, perhaps you want something like below.  Note that you *must* check the array bounds if you are using unknown input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *name = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "james";
    int length = strlen(name);
    char new[128] = "";
    char *d = new;
    /*
    Checking the parity of i inside the loop is a code smell, but
    we leave this as dead code for comparison to the original.  Simply
    skipping the unwanted indices is done below the dead code.
    for( int i = 0; i < length && i < sizeof new - 1; i += 1 ){
        if( (i+1) % 2 == 0 ){
            *d++ = name[i];
        }
    }
    */
    for( int i = 1; i < length && i < sizeof new - 1; i += 2 ){
        *d++ = name[i];
    }
    *d = '\0';
    printf("hello %s, your name has %i characters \n", name, length);
    printf("%s\n", new);
    return 0;
}
```

Many would think it more natural to write the loop as something like:

```
char *end = new + min(length, sizeof new);
for( name += 1; d < end; name += 2 ){                                      
        *d++ = *name;                                                      
}
```

and get rid of all of the indexing. Note, this requires a definition of `min` to compute the minimum, and it loses track of the beginning of the original `name`, so you would need to keep track of the start of the name or use a different variable for the loop.  Instead of indexing, you just keep track of three pointers; one to the character you want to copy, one to the destination to which you want to copy it, and one to the end of the destination buffer so you don't go past it.

Comment: Telling people learning via CS50 not to use `string` is likely to lead to confusion since that’s what the course teaches and what the `cs50.h` header uses.

Comment: ... which is among the worst failings of CS50.  The `string` typedef is deeply ingrained in the course, yet it is inherently confusing, even misleading.  There are some things to like about CS50, I guess, but overall, I have trouble recommending it.

Comment: The mere existence of the typedef is the source of confusion. Consider `char b[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c'}; string s = b;`  (Note that we could also write `char b[3] = "abc";` and it is important to understand how that is different from `char b[]="abc";`)  In that case, `s` is not a string (by the usual definition).  But its "cs 50 type" is clearly string.  It is a "string" from the perspective of cs50, but it is not a string in the usual sense of the word.  It is the typedef itself that causes the confusion, and the typedef must be avoided.